# "NameError: name 'int64' is not defined"

Tags: python, pandas

I am relatively new to pandas and while trying to define dtypes to read a large file, I am getting the following error: `NameError: name 'int64' is not defined`.

I made sure that pandas and numpy are installed and updated, but from what I understand this is a python error. 
I've gone through a few tutorials where nobody had this problem. See code below returning the error:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding="utf-16le", dtype={
    "time": int64,
    "created_date_sk": int64,
    "eventType": object,
    "itemId": int64,
    "fieldId": int64,
    "userId": int64
})

data.head()
```

Full trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manipulate.py", line 5, in
>   module "time": int64, NameError: name 'int64' is not defined

I would expect the `int64` type to be recognized, but it only seems to be able to read the int type. The object type seems to work.

Comment: Change to `np.int64`

Comment: Thanks! that got rid of the error. Getting a new one now, so i'll continue researching before posting again.

Answer (score 8):

The interpreter tells you that it is not recognized because int64 belongs to numpy.

Change your code to this (it complains about no file.csv in my filesystem, but this is normal):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding="utf-16le", dtype={
    "time": np.int64,
    "created_date_sk": np.int64,
    "eventType": object,
    "itemId": np.int64,
    "fieldId": np.int64,
    "userId": np.int64
})

data.head()
```

Or better yet, import it at the beginning:

```
from numpy import int64
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Please, rate the answer if you don't mind :) 
Thank you.

Comment: I did, but I don't have enough rep for it to show I believe

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting this error is because `int64` is not defined in the local python namespace. therefore using it in the dictionary throws an error. There are a couple of things you can do to fix this.

*Option 1: Use strings*

The simplest option is to enclose your datatypes inside strings. simply change `int64` to `"int64"` inside your dtype dictionary.

*Option 2: Use `numpy`*

Change `int64` to `np.int64`. (note this would require you importing the `numpy` package.

I like option2.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `int`. `pandas` `dtype` `int64` is mapped to python `int`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding="utf-16le", dtype={
    "time": int,
    "created_date_sk": int,
    "eventType": object,
    "itemId": int,
    "fieldId": int,
    "userId": int
})

data.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `int64` as a variable, You have to pass it as a string, Use the code given below:-

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding="utf-16le", dtype={
"time": 'int64',
"created_date_sk": 'int64',
"eventType": 'object',
"itemId": 'int64',
"fieldId": 'int64',
"userId": 'int64'
})

data.head()
```

I hope it may help you.

Comment: The other answers clearly show you don't _have to_ pass it as a string.

Comment: @Amadan if you are not passing as a string then you have to use `from numpy import int64`  AND now you can use without string also.

Comment: @Amadan you can use any option the output will be same. :)